# Can I download chrome extension directly from an Electron webview?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, webview, electron

Im working on a browser made with Electron and React and I need to be able to downlaod extension from chrome extension store but theres no button to do it so I cant download them.

We search online but didn't find anything to help.

Comment: Please specify the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are about some supported devtool extensions to manually add in electron app, maybe this will help

[Devtools extensions](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/devtools-extension)

If you are about dynamic extension adding, I suppose this can help

[electron-chrome-extensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-chrome-extensions)

But if you need to provide completely dynamic functionality in app to add extensions from chrome store, that won't be done easely, because **Chrome** and **Chromium engine** which electron uses to render a view are different, so it won't support a lot of natural browser features (like tabs, popups...)

P.S. For adding static extensions you can download them from Chrome store and use documentation below

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/extensions